# Prove: if $a \mid c$ and $b \mid d$ then $ab \mid cd$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Can this be proven? Or does it need a counter example?

> For any $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{N}$, if $a \mid c$ and $b \mid d$ then $ab \mid cd$

Need help.

Comment: @Arthur Or rather the definition of "$\mid$", really.

Comment: i'm quite new to this so i'm not sure how proving properly works, but i understand "|" as ie. a | c: c = a * k for any integer k.

Comment: @Jzy96 It should be a|c: c = ak for *some* integer k

Comment: yes that is correct, got mixed up with the question format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $a | c$, there exists a natural number $m$ such that $c = m a$. Similarly, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $d = n b$. Therefore, $cd = mn ab$ and $ab | cd$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that can be proven:

Remember that $x|y$ iff there is a whole number $z$ such that $y=xz$

Take any $a,b,c,d$

Suppose $a|c$ and $b|d$. So, there is a whole number $e$ such that $c=ae$ and whole number $f$ such that $d=bf$. So, $cd=aebf=abef$. So, there is a whole number $g$ (namely $g=ef$) such that $abg=cd$. So, $ab|cd$.